# function which provides counts of very specific elements in a list and return it

Tags: python, dictionary

create a function element_counts with 2 arguments. We are supposed to have both lists: a list of your data, and a list of elements you want counted in your data and return a dictionary: keys are the elements you wanted counted, and values are their counts in the data.

```
def element_counts(input_list, search_value):
    result = []
    dict.input_list()
    dict.search_value()
    return result
AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute 'input_list'

def find_all(input_list, search_value)
result = []
    for idx, num in enumerate(input_list):
         if num == search_value:
             result.append(idx)
    return result
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

def element_counts(list_data, list_elements):
    counts = random.count
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

and many other varieties. I am VERY NEW to python

def find_all(arg1, arg2)

Unknown expected/actual outputs.
```

Comment: If the assignment is to create a function named `element_counts`, why did you try to create a function named `find_all`?  I'm confused.

Comment: The directions said i could use what I got for B, and that was the function. I did not know how to reset it so it didnt work either way.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class and a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
from collections import Counter

def element_counts(input_list, search_value):
    counter = Counter(input_list)
    return {key: counter[key] for key in search_value}
```

Without using `Counter` you could create a frequency table:

```
def element_counts(input_list, search_value):
    freqs = {key: 0 for key in search_value}

    for item in input_list:
        if item in freqs:
            freqs[item] = freqs[item] + 1

    return freqs
```

Comment: hello, IronMan. thanks so much for your response. I am getting an error that says Count is not defined. I can only use len() and range()

Comment: Perhaps use `Counter`

Comment: my apologies it says counter is not defined. But im not sure if I can use an imported tool

Comment: i should have included that i cannot use any built-in functions besides len() and range().

Comment: Oh, I see, then you might be able to count the item frequencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def element_counts(input_list, search_value):
    search_list = [x for x in input_list if x in search_value]
    search_dict = {key:search_list.count(key) for key in search_value}
    return search_dict
```